# Any way to lock a view in MS Project 2010?

Tags: ms-office, ms-project

I have a simple view that consists of task, cost, and work hours in MS Project 2010. Is there any way to prevent users from editing the view - meaning hiding and adding extra columns?

Answer (score 0):

Tools | Options | Calculation-tab and select automatic calculation mode.

you can only do that on Task View.